# User database structure

Tags: php, html, mysql

Im not a webdev, Im learning all this stuff on the go and I stuck with this stage with my project.

I have a website people can register to use it, so I can store users already. I have a table with different items (item_id, item_name, item_owned). My problem is, every users should have the same list of item, but they can select if they have this item or not on thier own profile.

I could do it make the db and the items are selectable, the db shows 0 if you dont have it or 1 if you have it. But every user sees the same item_owned data and I need it to be user specific.

How can achive this? What structure should I use with the database? Do I need any special libraies beside HTML, PHP, SQL?

Thank you!

Comment: You have a table `users`, you have a table `items`. If you want to keep track of which user has which  items, you are better of creating an extra table `item_per_user` in which you store the `user_id` and `item_id`. Both will/could be a foreign key to the respective id field of each table

Comment: @DarkBee this is a great answer! Why is it a comment?!

Comment: Because it's a suggestion with no code attached to it?

Comment: @Guss please take remind yourself of the [tour] and read [ask] and [answer] - proper questions and answers here require some detail. DarkBee is right, this is just a generic suggestion (to a less-than-clear question)

Comment: Thank you @DarkBee! I can finally at least think about a solution. If I have more than one list of items I will need extra tables for them as well, I guess.

Comment: Your post has nothing to do with PHP or HTML really as far as I can see, it's primarily a database design issue.